# Reference request: Normal subgroup, free and transitive actions, stabilizers and complements

Tags: reference-request

Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and let $G$ act on a set $X$. Suppose the action of $K$ on $X$ is free and transitive. Then the stabilizer of any element in $X$ forms a complement of $K$.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a reference for this (or an equivalent of this) statement. I have only been able to find this stackexchange post ([Group Theory. Transitivity and Normal subgroups.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318666/group-theory-transitivity-and-normal-subgroups)).